# SCSS: use ampersand in pseudo class

Tags: css, sass

```
   .my-class {
      &:before{
        content:"";
        display:block;
        background:red;
        h1 ????{
          padding-top: 5px
        }
      }
    }
```

is it possible to use & in this location to have output like

```
h1.my-class:before {
  padding-top: 5px
}
```

Comment: So you have 2 elements with class `my-class`. One ( unknown ) and one `<h1 class="my-class" ` ? why don't you write 2 different style declarations then ?

Comment: If you really want to go this way, you could write: `.my-class {
  &:before{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    background:red;
  }
  @at-root h1#{&}:before {
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
}`

Comment: @MihaiT this is just a simple example, it's a not a real case, i hoped to have a short fix at this location, and don't want to rewrite all list of classes somewhere under

Comment: then have you checked the answer below ? Doesn't that solve your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to SCSS it this way::

```
.my-class {
  &:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: red;
    @at-root h1 {
      &.my-class {
        &:before {
          padding-top: 5px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution is the sass way of achieving this. +1 :)

Comment: Well, you could also go with: `@at-root h1#{&}:before {
    padding-top: 5px;
  }`

Comment: @AmauryHanser Sure, but without `:before` ;)

Comment: I hoped it has another solution :), at-root put me in a situation to write all classes again, what I'm hoping not to do :D, but it's still better than to have it somewhere else

Comment: @vrobik There is another drier solution, as Amaury Hanser said in his comment: `.my-class { &:before{ content:""; display:block; background:red; } @at-root h1#{&} { padding-top: 5px; } }`

Comment: @ReSedano, yes it solves the problem for this short example, but i have more complex situation ;) and it is important to do it from pseudo-class for me, also it is too risky to break something in future then you try to add a wrapper class, yes you can create a variable to prevent this, but its a different story if it's not in pseudo-class anymore :D
Like i said, i hoped to find a way to do it nice like then parent classes is added using &